# Cordova: android 7 crosswalk vs native

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk, phonegap

Just want to hear expert opinion. 
From your experience is it still worth to use latest Crosswalk (which recently has been announced to stop being actively developed) on Android 7 instead of native webview in terms of performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just finished a map app, where I use leaflet, vue and Framework7. The app uses a big overlay, has local tiles, a big virtual listview and a lot of markers on a small area.

If I use the app without crosswalk, the speed is "okay", but a little bit slow on modern devices on creating the virtual listview if you scroll with high speed.

On old devices the app is unuseable. One of my oldest devices is a Samsung Tab 2 with lineageos 13 (Android 6) and the app is very, very slow. On my Sony Tablet, Android 4.x the app is nearly dead.

With crosswalk it is running like formula 1 on modern devices and good on old devices.

So, in my next project, where I also need a lot of math, I will also use crosswalk.

Android 7 is nice and much better then older Androids, but slow device hardware is slow and not everybody has a top smartphone or tablet.

Answer (score 0):

'Than', NOT 'Then' huh! Croatians!